# Why is oscilloscope measuring a higher voltage at high impedance?

Tags: oscilloscope

The input to the scope is 358 MHz sine wave. It's coming from a four way power splitter, unsure of what is upstream of that. At 50 ohms its measuring 931 mV peak to peak. At 1Mohm its measuring 1.27V. Is the higher voltage measurement a result of the impedance mismatch at 1 Mohm?

Comment: 358 MHz + impedance mismatch = anything can happen! Reflections, standing waves, you name it. At 358 MHz you simply need to match everything. If you don't, the results will vary and it's a bit pointless to ask if what you measure is correct. Change the length of your cable and repeat the experiment, you'll get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything else, the sine wave output can just have a non-zero output impedance, so just loading it with 50 ohms makes the output voltage drop more than when loading it with 1M ohms.

Comment: It's coming from a 4 way power splitter. Unsure of what's upstream of that. Power splitter is 50 ohms though of course into 50 ohm cable.

Answer (score 1):

> *The input to the scope is 358 MHz sine wave. It's coming from a four
> way power splitter. Power splitter is 50 ohms.*

It's quite likely that the 1 Mohm input on your oscilloscope has something around 10 pF input capacitance and that is a reactive impedance of 45 ohms at 358 MHz. That still represents a non-insignificant loading of the splitter output. If the loading were insignificant then you would naturally expect the voltage to be twice 0.931 volts (1.862 volts).

If we called the scope impedance 50 ohms reactive then, compared to the 50 ohm resistive load that produces 0.931 volts, the reactive load would produce a voltage that is \$\sqrt2\$ higher than 0.931 volts i.e. 1.32 volts.

This is not a million miles from the 1.27 volts measured.

So, if you want a more exact answer you will need to establish the input impedance of your scope and probe lead.